# How to commit code changes from Eclipse to GitHub

Tags: eclipse, git, github, version-control, repository

I tried committing the entire project folder to my Github repository:
https://github.com/rahul-raj/SpringBoot

[image]

However when I try "Commit and Push", I get "master rejected non fast forward" error:

[image]

I tried pull/fetch, but it doesn't work either, getting "nothing to fetch" error:

[image]

When I try to commit and push the projects, now it says "0 Changes to be committed", but there are no such projects uploaded to my Github repository.
Can someone tell me how to fix this and push the project to my Github?
I was looking into several related Stack Overflow posts and nothing fixes my issue. How can I fix this through STS/EFclipse itself?

Comment: Does your local history start with the commits `622c4d5cc2c5d96718bc867a62bb63f3f94f4ac8` and `7aed4acb16d25c9c52f0783361ddf1fadf1f9bba`? Probably not and you have to select the option _"Force overwrite branch.."_ in the _Push Branch_ dialog. Maybe you need to [allow force push](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.12/admin/guides/developer-workflow/blocking-force-pushes-to-a-repository/) first.

Comment: @howlger
Awesome, that worked! thank you very much!

Comment: @howlger
However my other project listed in the directory got erased and current project was pushed. Whether the 'merge' option will do good?
or does it have to be 'Rebase'? https://i.imgur.com/el3MbMF.png

Comment: You should have created the new project in the previously cloned git repository with the other project (or merge the unrelated histories before doing a force push). Unfortunately, the force push overwrotes the other project with its history.

Comment: @RahulRaj Has your problem has been solved yet? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT 
Thank you for the note, marked the answer, earlier just marked +1 for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your local history differs from the already existing remote history (e. g. caused by an amend commit to an already pushed commit).

In this case, **in the *Push Branch dialog*** you have to **select** the option ***Force overwrite branch in remote if it exists and has diverged***. Maybe you need to [allow force push](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.12/admin/guides/developer-workflow/blocking-force-pushes-to-a-repository/) in your GitHub repository first.

Comment: If we overwrite branch in remote, does it remove other projects listed in repository and push the project?

Comment: @RahulRaj Unfortunately, yes (see my comment to your question above). There is only one history per branch and there is no concept for projects, but so-called [submodules](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_Submodules) in Git.